# NodeRunner.java missing

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I've been facing a problem for few days that is really driving me crazy. Since I've not found anyone else having this problem, I assume there is something that I'm doing wrong.

So I've downloaded rosjava and rosmake it. Then I ran rosmake on both **android_gingerbread** and **android_honeycomb_mr2** and they compiled with no failures. I've done the same on **android_tutorial_pubsub** as well. Now I'm modifying **android_tutorial_pubsub** to code my own program which some of my other friends have done too. Here comes the problem. I don't seem to be able to import the libraries "NodeRunner" and "DefaultNodeRunner". My jar file is simply missing these 2 and copying my friends jar files will fix this issue but will cause more trouble.

I was wondering what is it that I'm doing wrong that I miss these classes.

Thank you so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29582/noderunner.java-missing/) by [Sam_h](https://answers.ros.org/users/1955/sam_h/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2012-03-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-03-12**:
Are you using the deb release or trying to build rosjava from source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think NodeRunner was renamed to NodeMainExecutor in newer releases. Correct me if I’m wrong.

---

Originally posted by [kurmis](https://answers.ros.org/users/1980/kurmis/) with karma: 51 on 2012-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-03-27**:
Sort of... There has been a pretty large architectural shift since the last deb release. You are correct that NodeRunner no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the latest documentation and tutorials here:

http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/index.html
http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/android_core/html/index.html

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-04-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1